# How to add numbered/bulleted list in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-texteditor

How to do this in SwiftUI in `TextEditor`? I thought of reading return from keyboard. `TextField` has `onEditingChanged` and `onCommit`, but TextEditor doesn't.

In Notes app it detects automatically the numbered list, and has button for adding bulleted list.

I specifically want it to add number/bullet after empty line. (if possible)

[image]

Comment: this post may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/67503980/11419259

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can observe changes to the `TextEditor`'s text with `onChange`. Then, by doing `[text] newText`, you can capture both the old and new value.

- `text` is the previous text
- `newText` is the current text

If you compare these, you can ensure that bullet points are only added when the user is typing, and not when they're deleting.

<sup>Note that my implementation doesn't handle pasting large ranges of text yet.</sup>

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text = "\u{2022} "

    var body: some View {
        TextEditor(text: $text)
            .frame(height: 400)
            .border(Color.black)
            .onChange(of: text) { [text] newText in
                if newText.suffix(1) == "\n" && newText > text {
                    self.text.append("\u{2022} ")
                }
            }
    }
}
```

[image: When entering new lines, a bullet point is inserted at the start of the line]

Comment: thanks! maybe you have an idea, how to make proper indentation if point is multiline, i've tried just to add couple of `"   "` white spaces...(but didn't like it)

Comment: @MikeMaus I think in that case, it would be best to add the bullet points in a separate view (not inside the text editor). It would definitely be more complicated though, maybe post it into another question?

Answer (score 0):

Two improvements to @aheze's answer.

1. Removing the latest bullet if return is hit a second time.
2. Validating that bullet's are only created if that line itself begins with a bullet.

```swift
.onChange(of: text) { oldText, newText in
    let newLineIndex = oldText.lastIndex(where: { $0 == "\n" }) ?? oldText.startIndex
    if newText.count > oldText.count {
        if newText[newLineIndex...].starts(with: /\n?•/) { //line begins with a bullet
            if newText.suffix(3) == "\u{2022} \n"{ //user hits enter twice
                text.removeLast(3)
            } else if newText.suffix(1) == "\n" { //user hits enter once
                text.append("\u{2022} ")
            }
        }
    }
}
```